# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IF statements

Tags: php, mysql

*I'm trying to create a script for stats about visitors to my site. To do this, I record the visitor's IP, along with the date of the day and the number of times it has passed.
If this is the first visit, on all records in the database. But I want to count 1 pass per person per day.*

**What I am trying to do :** If the IP already exists, and the date is different from the day : we assign the date of the day, and increment the number of passing  (+1).

**The Problem :** When the date is different from the day, it is changed, BUT: the number of passing continues to increment even if the IP has already been counted that day.

It should only be done the next day, when the date changes...

**Here is my table structure :**

```
--
-- Table structure for table `ChartsGuests`
--

CREATE TABLE `ChartsGuests` (
    `IP_Guest` varchar(39) NOT NULL,
    `Date` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `Total` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`IP_Guest`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Here is the code :**

```
$IP_NewGuest = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$Today = date('d/m/Y');


$SQL = "INSERT INTO `ChartsGuests` (`IP_Guest` , `Date`, `Total`) VALUES ('".$IP_NewGuest."' , '".$Today."', 1)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE     
        Date = IF(Date != '".$Today."', VALUES(Date), '".$Today."'),
        Total = IF(Date != '$Today', VALUES(Total), Total + 1 )";



$REQ = $DB->prepare($SQL);
$REQ->execute() or die(var_dump($REQ->errorInfo()));

// echo $SQL;
```

It should only be done the next day, when the date changes... I do not know where the problem comes from, and this is the first time I use the "ON DUPLICATE KEY" with an "IF" ...

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Use https://piwik.org/ you'll get much more and won't have to reinvent the wheel..Also learn what sql parameters are, your code will be far more secure

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query.

Comment: MySQL prefers dates in the ISO-8601 format, that is `YYYY-MM-DD`. Using non-standard formats is problematic and can lead to sorting issues, they can't be indexed. You can always format any way you want when displaying data, something that's often highly user specific based on regional settings or preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your duplicate key is just on the IP address, but your table is really unique per IP Address/Date combo. As a result, visits on subsequent days overwrite the rows for the previous day.

If you change the logic of your table to have composite unique key on those two fields, the query will generate inserts for new (IP,Date) combos, and updates for (IP,date) combos that have been seen already.

If you fix that, you don't need the conditional (nor PHP for the current date), and you can just make this your SQL:

```
INSERT INTO `ChartsGuests` (`IP_Guest` , `Date`, `Total`)
 VALUES ('".$IP_NewGuest."' , CURDATE(), 1)  
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Total =  Total + 1 )";
```

Comment: What i need is to count each IP Adress once a day, and have the last visit date. I think you solution is much easier and would fit me if it could also handle that too... I don't know if I explained it well (excuse my english, I'm french, it's not easy to me to express my idea in english)

Comment: To clarify: If you had 10 IPs visit once per day for 10 days, would you want 10 rows or 100 rows?